# When i run 'npm install' command on my mac machine, am getting up a below error

Tags: vue.js

When i run 'npm install' command on my mac machine, am getting up a below error. help me to solve this:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...^1.7.0","sinon":"^4.0'
```

npm install

Comment: Can you give us the full stack error and all your relevant information about what your doing on which platform?

Comment: You have an issue in your `package.json` file, show us what's inside it so we can take a look and diagnose this for you.

Comment: @swonder Might also be in their `package-lock.json`.

Comment: Yes, it might be however you shouldn't need to edit the lock file since when you run `npm install` it overwrites the lock file.

Comment: I've also seen  this error a couple of times when people used npm mirrors (i.e. taobao) and received corrupted packages.